# Is it correct to say that if two parabolas touch, then tangents at the point of intersection have the same slope?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line

Is it correct to say that if two parabolas touch, then tangents at the point of intersection have the same slope?

If it is true, is there a neat geometric interpretation of the fact?

Comment: No.............

Comment: I believe the term you want is "touch", not "intersect"

Comment: If two curves meet tangentially, then they meet tangentially.

Comment: "Touch" is still pretty vague.

Comment: It all depends on your definition of tangency between curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a pair of lines on the plane with differnt slopes, any such pair will have an intersection point but by definition will not have the same slope at that point.

Comment: Note to readers: This (correct) answer was provided when the original question read "Is it correct to say that if two curves intersect, then tangents at the point of intersection have the same slope?"